# Sphinx 4 Demo and awt.Robot thread conflict

Tags: java, multithreading, awtrobot, sphinx4

I have an issue with the Sphinx demo Code. When I want to instantiate a Robot object, the program does nothing on the instantiation line, and doesn't continue the code. But the program is still running.

```java
ConfigurationManager cm;
cm = new ConfigurationManager(HelloWorld.class.getResource("helloworld.config.xml"));

Recognizer recognizer = (Recognizer) cm.lookup("recognizer");
recognizer.allocate();
// start the microphone or exit if the programm if this is not possible
Microphone microphone = (Microphone) cm.lookup("microphone");
if (! microphone.startRecording()) {
    System.out.println("Cannot start microphone.");
    recognizer.deallocate();
    System.exit(1);
}

Robot rob = new Robot();
    Result result = recognizer.recognize();
    if (result != null) {

        recognizer.deallocate();
        microphone.stopRecording();

        String resultText = result.getBestFinalResultNoFiller();
        System.out.println("You said: " + resultText + '\n');

    } else {
        System.out.println("I can't hear what you said.\n");
    }
```

I have also tried to launch the Sphinx code in a thread, and the Robot code in another thread. But it has the same problem.

I think the problem is with the thread "Java Sound Event Dispatcher", but I have no idea to solve it.

Without the line `Robot rob = new Robot();`, everything works fine.

Comment: could you show us your whole code?

Comment: Hello, this is the whole code based on this example :http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4#basic_usage I have juste had the libraby CMU SPHINX 4 and the line ... Robot rob = new Robot();